# How to Combine/merge two arrays in similar index of post request in node.js/express and convert in object to insert mongoose model

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a page that gets two arrays of input elements and sends them by post request to my app.js:

```
 <input type="text" name="titleAttr[]" > </input>
 <input type="text" name="descriptionAttr[]"> </input>
```

I created a Schema that receives an array with 2 fields, titleAttr and descriptionAttr, which correspond to the `<input>` elements above:

```
const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
 titulo: String,
 attrs:  [{
   titleAttr: String,
   descriptionAttr: String
  }]
});
```

I can insert the data manually and it works:

```
MyModel.bulkWrite([ { insertOne : { document: {
 title : "TEST",
 attrs: [
  {titleAttr : "test 1", descriptionAttr: "This is a test 1"},
  {titleAttr: "test 2", descriptionAttr: "This is another test"}
 ] 
 } } } 
]);
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRfMM.png) of the form  .

When the post request is sent from my form and I print it in app.js, I get these results:

```
console.log(req.body.titleAttr); //result: [ 'test 1', 'test 2' ]
console.log(req.body.descriptionAttr);// result: [ 'This is a test 1', 'This is another test' ]
```

This code doesn't work:

```
        ConceitoHTML.bulkWrite([ { insertOne : { document: {
         titulo : req.body.title,
         attrs: [
          {
           titleAttr: req.body.titleAttr,
           descriptionAttr: req.body.descriptionAttr
          }
         ]
        } } } ]);
```

I want to merge my two arrays and insert into MongoDB as an array of objects. How do I generate an array like the following?

```
const myArray = [
  { 
    titleAttr: req.body.titleAttr[0], 
    descriptionAttr: req.body.descriptionAttr[0]
  }, 
  {
    titleAttr: req.body.titleAttr[1], 
    descriptionAttr: req.body.descriptionAttr[1]
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this code below  **to get an array as expected what you want**:

```js
const {titleAttr, descriptionAttr} = req.body;
const myArray = [];

// check the length first, make sure it's same
if(titleAttr.length === descriptionAttr.length) {
  for(let i=0; i<titleAttr.length; i++) {
    myArray.push({ titleAttr: titleAttr[i], descriptionAttr: descriptionAttr[i] })
  }
}

console.log(myArray); // this is the array result
```

I hope it's can help you.